# Debug ASP.NET site on iphone

Tags: asp.net, iphone, debugging

I have an ASP.NET v4 application that is failing when I try to navigate on an IPHONE. it works fine on all browsers on a regular pc including Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE.

The problem is only on Safari on iphone device it keeps failing the validation on the page, as if the field is not populated even though it is.

I need to debug the app when I trigger it from iphone to see what is missing. I have Visual Studio 2017 on my local Machine which is Windows 10.

Is there a plugin, app or something I can do to debug the issue from my iphone? I don't have a Mac.

Comment: What do you mean by "failing" and "try to navigate"?

Comment: I mean when I click next to go to next page, it tells me "Field x is required" and highlight it as required, even though it contains a value in it. This only happens on iphone

Comment: It seems that problem is not related to navigation. However, the title of the question is still valid. I found one possibility: to use simulator on Mac. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html But it's not your case.

Comment: This article is quite old but could be still relevant: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/